# Jquery Auto Complete Does Not Append

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-autocomplete

Jquery newbie here.
My jquery append does not seem to be working.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am using jquery version 1.8.3 and UI 1.9.2.

Below is my code.

```
$('.tinputer').autocomplete({
        source: "http://localhost/myapp/items/search_item",
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
            $itemrow.find('#item_description').val(ui.item.description);
            $itemrow.find('#unit_price').val(ui.item.price);
            $itemrow.find('#qty').focus();
            verify_item(ui.item.value);
        }
    }).data("autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
        .append( "<a>" +  item.value + item.description + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Yw2Y7/1/
Try typing in the item box on the second row. The first row works.

The results get populated, and I get the drop down, but only value is shown. The item.description is not appended or it seems that the append section is completely ignored.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of this line:
 
 $itemrow.find('#item_description').val(ui.item.description);
Are you sure the item_description is returing value. Could you please make a jsfiddle or something

Comment: It's looking for the element named "item_description" in the table row that is nearest to the autocomplete element, and trying to add a value on selecting a value from the autocomplete dropdown. The code to work upon select is working fine with no issues.

Comment: Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Yw2Y7/1/

Comment: @you have to add .each function. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.tinputer').autocomplete({
source: projects,
minLength: 1,
select: function (event, ui) {
    var $itemrow = $(this).closest('tr');
    $itemrow.find('#item_description').val(ui.item.description);
    $itemrow.find('#unit_price').val(ui.item.price);
    $itemrow.find('#qty').focus();
    verify_item(ui.item.value);
}
}).

each(function(){               //This is the line added.


$(this).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a>" + item.value + " - " + item.description + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
} }           
 );
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/skhan/Yw2Y7/3/